# Plot simple graph with Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, plot

I need to plot simple graph with default Python 2.7.5 installation. The script runs on a web server, I have no access to install additional Python packages. My initial script was using matplotlib, but apparently this is not supported. Could you please recommend a package that does the work with the mentioned Python version? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used plotly a couple time and found it works well. It supports Python as well as JavaScript, so you should be well covered. 
Check it out here: https://plotly.com/python/

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, it still does not work. I cannot clearly see the Python traceback. I get the same error as with matplotlib: 500
Internal Server Error
An internal server error has occured.